# how to create a compile time const global class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, embedded, constants

trying to figure out how to create a const class in c++ in an embedded system

in c i can create a const struct in the text segment by doing this:

```
struct UART {
    uintptr_t baseaddr; int irqnum;
    const struct drivermethds *pMethods;
};
```

then:

```
const struct UART  uart0 = {
    .baseaddr = 0x40001000, .irqnum=5, .pMethods = &driverX
};
```

then create others just like that

the above would put uart0 in the text segment.

how do i do this in c++

i find all sorts of const stuff but not this

basically i cannot use a global constructor it must be compile time constructed

Comment: this should work with C++20.

Comment: We can do it in C++, if the class has a constructor, there are special precautions (`constexpr` or `constinit`), for aggregates like here, naming them explicitly is only possible since C++20. You can give an example and precise the C++ version you use for more precise explanations

Comment: Terminology: the code creates a global **object**, not a global class. A class is a compile-time thing. It doesn't exist at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the constructor of the class or structure is trivial, your provided example should work ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8E5azP69x)):

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

struct UART {
    ::std::uintptr_t baseaddr;
    // Etc.
};

extern UART const uart0 = {
    .baseaddr = 0x40001000,
};
```

Note that the `extern` storage class specifier has been added. In C, this is implicit for all file-scope const-qualified objects, but this isn't the case in C++. As per [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv#Notes):

> The const qualifier used on a declaration of a non-local, non-volatile non-template, non-inline variable that is not declared extern gives it internal linkage. This is different from C where const file scope variables have external linkage.

---

But in C++, it is often recommended to use *constexpr* global objects instead of const-qualified global objects. This can be achieved by specifying the [`constexpr` identifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

> The constexpr specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time.

This also requires a trivial constructor *or* a constexpr constructor (since C++20).

Example ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dxhEa983z)):

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

struct UART {
    ::std::uintptr_t baseaddr;
    // Etc.
};

constexpr UART uart0 = {
    .baseaddr = 0x40001000,
};
```

This doesn't – however – guarantee that the object is placed in `.text` (it will most likely be evaluated at translation-time and have its value inlined). Of course, You could also implement this object in assembly. As You're developing for an embedded system, this may actually be desirable.

Comment: So when I try to create a CONST class, I get this error message: <source>:22:21: error: passing 'const UART' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive], it seems the default is the "this" pointer for a class is or must be read write by default. I want it to be read only.

Comment: What is the program that gives that message? C++ does support cv-qualified methods (that is, they accept a *this* pointer whose source is cv-qualified). See the relevant page on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Member_functions_with_cv-qualifiers) for more information.